# get the Width of the textbox when opening the form in C#

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form as shown below, I want to save the width of the original textbox when the form loads, I have written code but not running, please help.

```
 namespace DieuKhienMayTinh
{
 public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        float Sizetb = textBox1.Width;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Sizetb);
    }
 }
}
```

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAcgN.png)

Comment: put `float Sizetb;` above the line `public Form2()`, then change `float Sizetb = textBox1.Width;` to `Sizetb = textBox1.Width;`

Answer (score 0):

You are storing textbox width in a method-local variable `Sizetb`. This wont compile at all.

Move it out to class level:

```cs
namespace DieuKhienMayTinh
{
 public partial class Form2 : Form
 {
    // class level member field available for each method in class
    private float Sizetb;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Sizetb = textBox1.Width;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Sizetb);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I am a new member: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: But, I believe you can still accept the answer (look for a checkmark, I believe)

Comment: sorry, I'm new, and I've accepted the answer